# Record Video in background with different UI in foreground

Tags: iphone, ios7, avcam

Can I record the video in background without the camera feed to be displayed onscreen using AVCam? Is that possible? If that is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible . You can refer this apple document

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html